# Using a jquery script as a function

Tags: jquery, function

I would like to use this script as a function :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var kkeys = [],
        login = '76,79,71,73,78'; //login
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
        if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(login) >= 0) {
            $(document).unbind('keydown', arguments.callee);
            return hs.htmlExpand(this, {
                contentId: 'highslide-html-loginform',
                wrapperClassName: 'mod_cdlogin',
                outlineType: 'rounded-white',
                align: 'auto',
                anchor: 'auto',
                dimmingOpacity: 0,
                slideshowGroup: 'mod_cdlogin_loginform'
            })
        }
    });
});
```

So I could have this code in my js part a call a function in another file, for example `codelogin('mycode')` and 'mycode' would be 76,79,71,73,78 in that case.
I tried many things but it's not working. The script as itself works fine, but I'm not used to work with jQuery so that might be my problem, I looked for a way to do it but I'm kind of lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code in function and call it from other script block of file.

```
<script>


jQuery(function($){

    function YourFunName(myCode){
    {
    var kkeys = [];     
    login = myCode;//login
    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
    kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
    if( kkeys.toString().indexOf( login ) >= 0 )
    {
    $(document).unbind('keydown',arguments.callee);
    return hs.htmlExpand(this, { contentId: 'highslide-html-loginform', wrapperClassName: 'mod_cdlogin', outlineType: 'rounded-white', align: 'auto', anchor: 'auto', dimmingOpacity: 0, slideshowGroup: 'mod_cdlogin_loginform' })
    }
    });
    }

     YourFunName('76,79,71,73,78');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nearly there. Here's one implementation I was able to work up that accepts a code, in this case the string "jonathan", a callback function and an optional element to operate on. By default the code will bind to the `document` object if no other option is requested:

```
// When 'jonathan' is entered, fire off alertSuccess
bindcode ("jonathan", alertSuccess);

// Our callback function
function alertSuccess () {
    alert("You did it!");
}

// The bindcode function takes a code, a callback, and an optional element
function bindcode( code, callback, element ) {
    var input = [];
    // When the keypress event occurs on either your element, or the document
    $(element || document).on("keypress", function(e){
        // Push the new character onto the input array
        input.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        // Convert to a string and check for presence of code
        if (input.join("").indexOf(code) > -1) {
            // Unbind the keypress event, and fire off callback
            $(this).off("keypress");
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rQU4A/